# Running program from console with parameters

Tags: c

My question is how to write a fuction with which I will can run a program from console with following parameters:
program.exe -i input.txt -o output.txt -t 1/2/3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char substitute(char letter, char* cipher)
{
    int i;
    int cipher_length = strlen(cipher);
    char substitution = letter;

    for(i = 0; i < cipher_length; ++i)
        {
            if(cipher[i] == substitution)
            {
            substitution = cipher[(i%2) ? (i-1) : (i+1)];
            break;
            }
        }
    return substitution;
}

int main()
{
    char c;
    int t;
    FILE *plik = fopen( "input.txt", "rt" );
    FILE *encoded=fopen("output.txt","wt");
    char* cipher1 = "GADERYPOLUKIgaderypoluki";
    char* cipher2 = "POLITYKARENUpolitykarenu";
    char* cipher3 = "KACEMINUTOWYkaceminutowy";

    printf("Choose the cipher\n");
    printf("[1]GA-DE-RY-PO-LU-KI\n");
    printf("[2]PO-LI-TY-KA-RE-NU\n");
    printf("[3]KA-CE-MI-NU-TO-WY\n");

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        c = getc( plik );
        switch(t)
    {
    case 1:
            putc(putchar(substitute(c, cipher1)),encoded);
            break;
    case 2: putc(putchar(substitute(c, cipher2)),encoded);
            break;
    case 3: putc(putchar(substitute(c, cipher3)),encoded);
            break;
    }
}
    fclose( plik );  
    fclose(encoded);
}
```

I was given sth like this, but I don't know how to use it:

```
    int function(int argc, char*argcv[])
    {
        int i;
        char *string,*input,*output;
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
          {

          }
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Note that by UNIX convention, an option can have two forms, the short form of a single hyphen followed by a character, `-i`, or the long form of a double hyphen followed by a meaningful sequence of characters, `--input`.

Comment: I suggest looking at [`getopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opterr.3.html) from `<unistd.h>`. It makes doing this fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `int argc` contains the number of parameters in the command line.

The parameter `char *argv[]` is an array with all the strings typed in the command line.

This way, you can retrieve the command line parameters as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("parameter %d = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
}
```

You can handle then the parameters passed in the command line:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        ...
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0) {
            doSomething(argv[i+1]);
        }
        ...

    }
}
```

To break the string you can use the following code:

```
    // ...
    char buffer[256];
    char *p1 = NULL;
    char *p2 = NULL;
    int value = 0;
    char old = 0;

    strcpy(buffer, argv[7]);
    p1 = buffer;
    p2 = buffer;

    do {
            // parse until the delimiter
            while (*p1 != '/' && *p1 != '\0') {
                    p1++;
            }

            // save delimiter value
            old = *p1;

            // convert the string to int
            *p1 = '\0';
            value = atoi(p2);
            p1++;

            // do something with the value
            printf(">> value %d\n", value);

            // goto the next token
            p2 = p1;

    } while (old != '\0');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do something with this :)

Comment: I have a problem, in command line at argv[7] I will give a number 1/2/3 and my question is how to put this number 1/2/3 to a switch statement ? I know it's not an integer, can I do it somehow ?

Comment: You can try the following code: